# Tensorflow DNNLinearCombinedClassifier NaN loss during training

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

new to Tensorflow and trying to classifier data to 5 classes. If I run the code I got an:

```
ERROR:tensorflow:Model diverged with loss = NaN.
INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: <class 'tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.monitors.NanLossDuringTrainingError'>, NaN loss during training.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "net_version2.py", line 83, in <module>
tf.app.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 30, in run
sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "net_version2.py", line 79, in main
train_and_eval()
  File "net_version2.py", line 72, in train_and_eval
m.fit(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(df_train, True), steps=200)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 219, in fit
max_steps=max_steps)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 507, in _train_model
max_steps=max_steps)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3530, in get_controller
yield default
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 507, in _train_model
max_steps=max_steps)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3004, in device
yield
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 507, in _train_model
max_steps=max_steps)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/graph_actions.py", line 282, in _supervised_train
return loss
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3530, in get_controller
yield default
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/graph_actions.py", line 281, in _supervised_train
None)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/supervised_session.py", line 318, in run
run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/recoverable_session.py", line 54, in run
run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/coordinated_session.py", line 70, in run
self._coord.join(self._coordinated_threads_to_join)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py", line 383, in join
six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py", line 686, in reraise
raise value
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/coordinated_session.py", line 66, in run
return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/monitored_session.py", line 107, in run
induce_stop = monitor.step_end(monitors_step, monitor_outputs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/monitors.py", line 396, in step_end
return self.every_n_step_end(step, output)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/monitors.py", line 1086, in every_n_step_end
raise NanLossDuringTrainingError
tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.monitors.NanLossDuringTrainingError: NaN loss during training.
```

My code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.DEBUG)

CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS = []
CONTINUOUS_COLUMNS = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]

GOAL_COLUMN = "goal"

def build_estimator(model_dir):
  """Build an estimator."""
  a = tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("a")
  b = tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("b")
  c = tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("c")
  d = tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("d")
  e = tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("e")
  f = tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("f")
  g = tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("g")

  wide_columns = [a, d, b, c, e, f, g]
  deep_columns = [a, d, b, c, e, f, g]

  return tf.contrib.learn.DNNLinearCombinedClassifier(
        linear_feature_columns=wide_columns,
        dnn_feature_columns=deep_columns,
        dnn_hidden_units=[20, 10, 5],
        n_classes=3)

def input_fn(df, train=False):
  """Input builder function."""
  continuous_cols = {k: tf.constant(df[k].values) for k in CONTINUOUS_COLUMNS}
  feature_cols = dict(continuous_cols)

  if train:
    label = tf.constant(df[GOAL_COLUMN].values)
    return feature_cols, label
  else:
    return feature_cols

def train_and_eval():
  """Train and evaluate the model."""
  df_train = pd.read_csv(
      tf.gfile.Open("./train.csv"),
      skipinitialspace=True)
  df_test = pd.read_csv(
      tf.gfile.Open("./test.csv"),
      skipinitialspace=True)
  model_dir = "./models"
  print("model directory = %s" % model_dir)

  m = build_estimator(model_dir)
  m.fit(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(df_train, True), steps=200)
  print (m.predict(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(df_test)))
  results = m.evaluate(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(df_train, True), steps=1)
  for key in sorted(results):
    print("%s: %s" % (key, results[key]))

def main(_):
  train_and_eval()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  tf.app.run()
```

An exemple from my csv is:

```
a,b,goal,c,d,e,f,g
21,93895,1,18161,1362,0,-1,-1
21,93929,1,5706,1485,134,-1,-1
```

If I change the *n_classes*-parameter to 2 (default) I got a result tensor `[1, 1, ..., 1, 1]` with mean of 1.0. Every class-setting above 1 throws the error above.

```
  return tf.contrib.learn.DNNLinearCombinedClassifier(
        linear_feature_columns=wide_columns,
        dnn_feature_columns=deep_columns,
        dnn_hidden_units=[20, 10, 5],
        n_classes=3)
```

Same is if I use only a DNNClassifier. If I use an Regressor, I got values between -5 and 10 for possible goal values of 1 up to 5.

Hope anyone has an idea to solve this problem.

Comment: The problem can be solved by scaling the target from 0 to 4. This works for me.